# System.Net.Http Dependency Mismatch between Nuget package and ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, dll, asp.net-core, nuget-package, asp.net-core-middleware

### Background

I'm trying to write some middleware to do custom authentication with ASP.NET Core.  Because I'm dependent on some proprietary code using .NET framework, I'm using the .Net Framework version of ASP.NET Core rather than the .NET Core version of ASP.NET Core.

Initially, I built the middleware directly into an ASP.NET Core app and installed my proprietary dependencies with Nuget.  This worked just fine.

Next, I wanted to build a Nuget package so that my middleware could be shared internally by several ASP.NET Core web services.  So I created a class library and added the middleware code.  I installed various ASP.NET Core Nuget Packages and my proprietary Nuget packages to resolve dependencies and built the Nuget Package.  I installed it in an ASP.NET Core app successfully.

### The Problem

When I try to run the middleware, I get the following: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The ASP.NET Core app seems to use `System.Net.Http 4.0.0`

### Attempt 1

Naturally, I looked at the class library for its `System.Net.Http` dependency.  It was pulled down in a Nuget package, appropriately named `System.Net.Http`.  I installed that package to the ASP.NET Core app successfully (or so it told me).  I ran the app and the middleware failed with the same error.  Confused, I went back and looked at the Nuget packages.  `System.Net.Http` was missing!  I installed it again "successfully", but searching for the package again showed it wasn't installed.

I disabled automatic package restoration, I cleared the Nuget cache, and tried again.  No luck.  The package thinks it's successfully installed, but it never really works.

Here's the relevant section of the ASP.NET Core app's project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ProprietaryLibrary": "1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "MyMiddlewarePackage": "1.0.0",
    "ProprietaryDependency": "1.0.0",
    "ProprietaryDependency": "1.0.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0" <--- This updates to 4.1.0 if I install that nuget package, but nothing really happens.
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  }
}
```

### Attempt 2

It occurred to me that I may have set up the class library incorrectly.  So I went to https://github.com/aspnet/Security and copied the project structure of their middleware.  I again installed my dependencies (a much smaller list!), and it built successfully.  I again built a Nuget package and installed it to the ASP.NET Core app.  But again, I got the same error about Version 4.1.1.0.

Here is the project.json of the new class library:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ProprietaryLibrary": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing references `System.Net.Http` at all!

If you're curious about that proprietary library, here's the reference tree. All the blanked out stuff is proprietary DLLs.  So I don't see any `System.Net.Http` reference there, either.  I'm not saying it's not there, but I can't see it.  And even if it was there, why would that proprietary library work just fine directly embedded in the ASP.NET Core app?

[image: Proprietary Library Dependency tree]

### Summary

I can't figure out where `System.Net.Http 4.1.1.0` is referenced, and I can't make ASP.NET Core update to use anything newer than `4.0.0.0`.  But if I paste my code and download the dependencies directly in the ASP.NET Core app, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

### Update

It looks like the problem is the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` Nuget package.  Every time it is installed, it nukes the new version of `System.Net.Http`.  Any ideas on how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  It's the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` that is the problem.

After narrowing it down, it looks like Microsoft is aware of the problem: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1046.  They'll be releasing a fix within a month, it sounds like.

Here is the commit that fixed it: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/commit/0f429324c54e380eeed235fea2bdfabb3639f43e